# I get an error that doesnť make sense to me in php

Tags: php, function

I have a function and at the start of it a define a variable $result and it gives me this error - syntax error, unexpected token ";" - it says on line 6 and on line 6 in my whole code is the line $result; here its the second line. thanks for your answers.
here is the function

```
    empty_input_signup($username, $email, $password, $confirm_password){
    $result;
    if(empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username) || empty($username)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `$result;` as a line has no purpose whatsoever. Remove it or set a default, though that's already being done in your else statement

Comment: I see that i didn't rewrite the variables in the if statement so it always only checks for username but i fixed that, that is not the problem please ignore it Im just dumb

Comment: How would PHP be aware your function is a function?

Comment: oh man im dumb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to use `function` word before the function declaration. And the first $result will be not get you expected effect, PHP will try to execute it. So, the correct code will look like this

```php
<?php

function empty_input_signup($username, $email, $password, $confirm_password)
{
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($confirm_password)) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Instead answering - flag question for closing.